# Nested loop if php

Tags: php

I try to run the code below:

- 1) I check first char of $string_result
- 2) if first char of $string_result match in array first_char it will output string    result
- 3) if first char equal to "n", I compare the first two char of $string_result to array second_char
- 4) If i remove the nested if n else, it works well. Did I do some logic errors there?

  ```
  <?php
      $string_result = "nyanyi";
      function awalan_pe($string_result){
      $first_char = array("m", "n", "r", "l", "w");
      $second_char = array("ny", "ng");
      $result = (substr($string_result, 0,2));
      foreach ($first_char as $value){
      if ($string_result[0] == $value) {
          $final_result = "pe".$string_result;

          if(($string_result[0] == $value) == "n"){
              foreach ($second_char as $value){
                  if($result == $value){
                  $final_result = "pe".$string_result;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      else{
          return null;
      }
   }
  return $final_result;
  }
  echo awalan_pe($string_result);
  ?>
  ```

sadly it returns null.

Comment: "if(($string_result[0] == $value) == "n"){" you are comparing a boolean with a string here, probably not what you intended to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in_array will help in this situation, look following customized code for your code.

```
<?php
    $string_result = "nyanyi";
    function awalan_pe($string_result){
    $first_char = array("m", "n", "r", "l", "w");
    $second_char = array("ny", "ng");
    $result = (substr($string_result, 0,1)); //store 1st Char
    $result2 = (substr($string_result, 0,2)); //store 1st and 2nd Char
    $flag=0;
    if($result === "n") //if first char is "n"
    {
        if(in_array($result2, $second_char)) //to check whether entry is present in array or not
        {
            $final_result= "String Found";
            $flag=1;
        }
    }
    else{
        if(in_array($result, $first_char))
        {
            $final_result= "String Found";
            $flag=1;
        }
    }
    if($flag == 0)
    {
    return null;
    }

return $final_result;
}
echo awalan_pe($string_result);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It will `return null` as you don't stop the iteration after you find the correct one.

Move return `$final_result` after you find your final result like

```
$final_result = "pe".$string_result;
return $final_result;
```

Answer (score 0):

By your way, i modified:

```
public function awalan_pe($string_result){
        $first_char = array("m", "n", "r", "l", "w");
        $second_char = array("ny", "ng");
        $str_len = strlen($string_result);
        for($i = 0; $i <= $str_len; $i++){
            foreach($first_char as $f_char){
                if(substr($string_result,$i,$i+1) == $f_char){
                    if(substr($string_result,$i,$i+1) == "n"){
                        for($j=0; $j <= $str_len; $j++){
                            foreach($second_char as $s_char){
                                if(substr($string_result,$i,$i+2) == $s_char){
                                    return "in second array value:" .$s_char;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "not in first array";
    }
```